# Google Maps not working in Django template on App Engine development server

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates, google-maps

When I add this script to a plain HTML file's HEAD section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

and I run this script on the body onload,

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

then I see the Google map just fine.

However, the same does not work when in a Django template. (Yes, I am new to Django :)
I get all the code in the initialize function to run, but no map shows up. Page stays blank.

I assume it has something to do with Django, and the GAE dev server, and how the Google Maps js API is referenced, but I don't know how to fix.

Thanx much.

Edit:

My Django template looks like this (There are no Django specific tags or anything yet.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    dir="ltr"
    xml:lang="en"
    lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/main.css" />

    <script src="/site_media/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(event) {
            initialize();
        });

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <center>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:60%; height:70%;">Why the heck is the map not showing?</div>
    </center>

  </body>
</html>
```

And the rendered HTML source of that template from the browser looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    dir="ltr"
    xml:lang="en"
    lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/main.css" />

    <script src="/site_media/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(event) {
            initialize();
        });

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 8,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <center>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:60%; height:70%;">Why the heck is the map not showing?</div>
    </center>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does your Django template look like?  What is the source of the page when you retrieve the page?

Comment: @David Underhill: I added my template above. Do you mean what does the rendered HTML source look like in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DOCTYPE` is causing the problem.  If I remove that from your code, then the map displays.

There are [some threads](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/search?group=google-maps-js-api-v3&q=doctype&qt_g=Search+this+group) on the [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3) that discuss this problem.

Comment: THANX. I haven't had time to look at this since I posted it, but it's been bugging my brain all the while. It works perfectly. Now I can continue. Thanx for taking the time to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is (directly) related to the GAE development server or Django - it looks like your page's HTML is loading just fine.

I suspect your problem may be the jQuery reference.  Perhaps jQuery is not being loaded, and thus your script stops executing when it tries to access `$(document)` but fails because a `ReferenceError` is thrown.

I would check that your link to load the jQuery library is working by manually accessing it in your browser (i.e., browse to http://localhost:8080/site_media/js/jquery.min.js (or wherever you are running your development server) and make sure it works).  If not, then fix your app.yaml file so that it is properly setup to serve /site_media/js/jquery.min.js.

Comment: Thanx for the tip, but no its not that. I did verify that my jQuery works and that my script is executing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this I think and I fixed it by just doing the Google Maps initialize from google's own method:

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

I know I tried to do this (by default) in jQuery's ready but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Thanx for the tip. I think though that cope360's answer hit the root of the problem and so I marked his as the right answer.